# expression to format date as Su 1 in SSDT

Tags: sql-server-data-tools, ssrs-tablix

I am working in SSDT creating a report. Trying to get a row/field to display "**Su 1**" , "**Mo 2**" for the day of week + increment the number of that day in the pay period.

> First half of code works. returning  (Mo, Tu, We, Th, Fr etc)

```
= LEFT(FORMAT(Fields!TransactionDate.Value,"ddd"),2)
```

> **Issue** Need to complete 2nd half to provide the increment count for the pay period.

```
      Code: + " "+ (STR(FORMAT(Fields!TransactionDate.Value,"d"))
```

Answer (score 0):

FIX! bottom line of code produced the result I needed.

```
=LEFT(FORMAT(Fields!TransactionDate.Value,"ddd"),2) 
+ " "+ CStr(CInt(Format(Fields!TransactionDate.Value,"dd")))
```